# How to disable the click event for the customized checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I was trying to disable a customized checkbox using jquery once the class `disabled` is added. Below is my code what I tried so far.

```
$('span').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
$('.disabled').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
span{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: gray;
}
span.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
cite.fa-check{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 1px;
    display: none;
}
span.active cite.fa-check{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My event should not worked if I add class `disabled` to my checkbox. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gt737sd/1/)

Comment: do you want to make it disabled forever

Comment: use delegate function `$('.disabled').on('click',function(e){`

Comment: Its dynamic @NoDownvotesPlz i know a solution `unbind` click but I looking for something which I dont wanna `bind` it again

Comment: It would be better to use actual checkboxes for accessibility. Then use a div/iimage/whatever to trigger clicks on these check boxes, that you can hide. You'd have to check after the click if the checkbox is enabled, then you'd enable the div/image/whatever also.

Comment: @TamilSelvan That's not delegation syntax. Delegation is `$(document).on('click', '.disabled', ...)`

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8gt737sd/12/

Comment: $('.disabled').click(function(e){
    return false;
    e.stopPropagation();
    
});


$('span').click(function(e){
    
    if($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
    {
        return false;
    
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update code to below . jquery not() selector avoid event on mentioned element. you don't need to use $('.disabled') click event.

see working demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gt737sd/4/)

```
$('span').not('.disabled').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thats what I looking for easy simplistic and reliable. Thanks. +1 for the simplistic answer

Comment: hepply to help you .. you can also accept my  answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use   `hasClass`

you need only this js

```
$('span').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass( "disabled" )==false){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gt737sd/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the clicked element is disabled or no by checking for the class if exists or not

```
$('span').click(function(e){

    if($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
    {
        return false;

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});


$('.disabled').click(function(e){
    return false;
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```